# React Native reset password with Firebase using the oopCode as a verification code in my app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, express, firebase-authentication

Currently I know you can send a resetPasswordLink that will allow you to reset the password in the browser by default. I believe firebase uses the oopCode to verify the user. Is there a way to send a reset password link that within the email template I can provide an actionCode the user can copy and paste into the app as verification which will then allow them to move on to the next screen and update their password?

Here is the functionality I'm looking to accomplish:

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itPtm.png)

[second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yFyQ.png)

[third screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuxHx.png)